# System function to read value of a signal

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

```
Error: : (vlog-7027) Hierarchical reference not allowed from within a package.
```

Is there a system function which can be used to get past this? I know that that using an interface is the right way to read a signal.

What is the reason for not allowing hierarchical references in a package(apart from portability)?

Comment: There is no standard system function to do it, but you can write your own.  You just need to pass the path as a quoted string to it. Just remember that the order of initialization is undefined in verilog (as between static vars and initial blocks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `package` construct is all about sharing and portability. The use of packages demands a strict compilation order dependency. Adding hierarchical references to a package breaks this ordering.

It most cases, using virtual interfaces is a solution to this issue. There are other suggestions in my [DVCon paper](https://verificationacademy.com/resources/technical-papers/the-missing-link-the-testbench-to-dut-connection). Of course, if you could share exactly what you are attempting to do, then I could direct you towards the best course of action.

Comment: I agree on the good practices of writing package. But sometimes all I want for a quick debug is a `bit [31:0] bus = $read_bus(<Full Path>)` system function to extract value of this bus from simulator's memory instead of forcing me to write an interface.

Comment: Tools allow you to do this if you provide the right debugging access switches. Check your User Manual.